# xml parsing in adobe alchemy

Tags: xml, parsing, adobe, alchemy

hello can you prvide an example how to parse xml file in adobe alchemy.
im trying to work on expat, however i got no luck on passing of bytearrays to 
and from the c code.

do i need to pass the byte array of file to the alchemy, or is it enough to pass the filename.

thanks.

cbs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse xml within Alchemy, you'll need to use a [C/C++ parsing library](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/).

As for getting the xml into Alchemy:

- The simplest way would be to simply pass the xml string into the function and Alchemy will marshal it for you.
- Alternatively you could use [supplyFile](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Documentation:Developing_with_Alchemy:AS3_API#CLibInit)/fopen to open a "virtual file" that maps to a ByteArray.
- You could also copy the ByteArray straight into Alchemy's RAM.

[Here is a comparison](http://blog.debit.nl/2009/03/using-bytearrays-in-actionscript-and-alchemy/) of methods to move ByteArrays into Alchemy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I passed an embedded file:

[Embed(source="Test.txt", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public var TestClass:Class;

private function echo():String
{
  var loader:CLibInit=new CLibInit;
  var lib:Object = loader.init()
  var data:Object = new TestClass();
  lib.test(data.length, data);
}

The C code is:

static AS3_Val test(void *self, AS3_Val args)
{
  int length;
  AS3_Val data=AS3_Undefined();
  AS3_ArrayValue(args, "IntType, AS3ValType", &length, &data)

unsigned char buffer[length];
  AS3_ByteArray_seek(buffer, 0, SEEK_SET);
}